# Feasibility of Manipulating (Increasing) Ethereum's Basefee (Gas Price)

Tags: gas, gas-price, decentralization, ethereum-design

Has anyone explored how feasible it is to manipulate the block.basefee (i.e., the gas price) on Ethereum? After running some numbers, it seems more achievable than initially thought. Consider this: filling up a block with a theoretical limit of 30,000,000 gas at roughly 50 gwei per unit of gas equates to about 1.5 ETH to increase the basefee by 12.5%. Repeat this process six times, and you've doubled the basefee. The potential repercussions on Ethereum's ecosystem could be significant, though I'm not aware of any previous instances where this has occurred.

Another aspect to consider is the Proposer Builder Separation (PBS) mechanism. For an attack to succeed, a user would need to ensure their transactions populate the immediate succeeding blocks, ideally for another 5 blocks to make the manipulation effective. However, to give potential attackers some leeway, let's say managing this feat for 10-20 blocks isn't outside the realm of possibility, instead of just 5.

We should also factor in priority fees. However, for the majority of transactions (>90%) within a block, priority fees are typically under 10% of the basefee. Hence, they might not significantly impact this analysis—except perhaps for the top-tier transactions, which isn't necessary to manipulate the basefee.

Curious to hear your thoughts and any additional insights into this potential vulnerability.